I have a shopping app component that I only want to show on a particular page. Tried useLocation but the component has dynamic ids
I want to know how I can make my "page" variable in the below code dynamic, so I can properly compare it with the location.pathname variable which will have dynamic page ids.
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function AddToCart() {
  function IsItemPage() {
    const page = '/item_page';
    const location = useLocation();
    console.log(location);
    if (location.pathname == page) {
      return true;
    };
  }

  return IsItemPage() && ( 
    <span className='add-to-cart'>
      <button>Add Item</button>
      <button>Cart</button>
    </span>
  );
}

export default AddToCart;

Now each item I open from the home page has a unique id for example: "/item_page/2" and obviously I cannot hard code it. If I provide the absolute path to the "page" variable like "/item_page/1" or something, the component is working as expected but only for that particular item with 'id: 1'. But I need to be able to achieve this for every item I open from the home page.
So how can I achieve this?

Why do u have to check the location instead of just adding in the desired component or the page?

If you just want to check if the current URL path matches a specific path (or pattern) then you can use the useMatch hook, no need to re-invent the wheel.
Example:
useMatch("/item_page/:id?");

This will match any "/item_page" and "/item_page/XYZ" sub-route path, returning a defined PathMatch object for matches, or null for non-matches.
Code:
import { useMatch } from "react-router-dom";

function AddToCart() {
  const isItemPage = useMatch("/item_page/:id?");

  return (
    isItemPage && (
      <span className="add-to-cart">
        <button>Add Item</button>
        <button>Cart</button>
      </span>
    )
  );
}

export default AddToCart;

Since it seems you want to render this AddToCart component with select routes, an alternative is to conditionally render it with the select routes via a layout route component. Layout routes are used to render common UI and apply common logic to a set of nested route components.
Example:
function AddToCart() {
  return (
    <span className="add-to-cart">
      <button>Add Item</button>
      <button>Cart</button>
    </span>
  );
}

import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const ItemPageLayout = () => {
  ...
  return (
    ...
    <Outlet />
    <AddToCart />
    ...
  );
};

<Routes>
  {/* Non-Item_page routes */}
  ...

  <Route path="item_page">
    <Route element={<ItemPageLayout />}>
      {/* Item pages with layout and AddToCart buttons */}
      <Route index element={<h1>Item Page</h1>} />
      <Route path=":id" element={<h1>Item Detail Page</h1>} />
      ...
    </Route>

    {/* Item pages without layout and no AddToCart buttons */}
    ...
  </Route>
</Routes>


Use useLocation hook from react-router-dom to extract the current pathname and dynamically check if it matches the expected pattern for an item page.
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function AddToCart() {
   const location = useLocation();
   const pathSegments = location.pathname.split('/');
   
   function IsItemPage() {
     if (pathSegments[0] === '/item_page' && pathSegments.length > 1) {
       const itemId = pathSegments[1];
       console.log('Item ID:', itemId);
       return true;
      }
      return false;
    }

    return IsItemPage() && (
       <span className='add-to-cart'>
         <button>Add Item</button>
         <button>Cart</button>
       </span>
     );
 }

export default AddToCart;


Just FYI this breaks the Rules of Hooks by calling the useLocation hook in a callback function.

Please check now I've updated code.

Have you tested this code? What value do you think pathSegments[0] will be given a "/item_page/XYZ" path value? What if location.pathname is just "/item_page" (like in OP's code snippet), do you think IsItemPage will return true like OP is likely expecting?

I would suggest you to do condition check on the parent component instead of the child component.
Item page:
function ItemPage() {

    return ( 
        <>
           {condition && <AddToCart />}
        </>
    );
}

export default AddToCart;

Add to Card:
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function AddToCart() {

    return ( 
        <span className='add-to-cart'>
          <button>Add Item</button>
          <button>Cart</button>
        </span>
    );
}

export default AddToCart;

If u wanna display the add to cart on every item page.You don't have to include the condition check.
